# Jquery não exclui linhas da tabela

Tags: jquery

Tenho o formulário abaixo do qual quando clico em **Adicionar mais Pet**, ele adiciona mais um ***panel*** normalmente:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Porém quando clico em **Remover**, ele remove apenas os botões e os panels continuam. Vejam o código:

```
<table border="0" style="width: 100%">
            <tr class='linhas'>
            <td>
                <div class="panel panel-primary">
                 <div class="panel-heading">
                   <i class="fa fa-paw fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i>  DADOS DO PET
                  </div>
                 <div class="panel-body">
                     <div class="table-responsive">
                         <div class="form-group">
                          <label>Espécie:</label>
                          <select name="Especie" class="form-control">
                            <option value="Canino">Canino</option>
                            <option value="Felino">Felino</option>
                          </select>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                         <label>Nome do Pet:</label>
                         <input type="text" name="NomePet" class="form-control" required="required">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                         <label>Aniversário do Pet:</label>
                         <input type="date" name="AniversarioPet" class="form-control" data-inputmask="'alias': '99/99/9999'" required="required">
                       </div>
                       <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Gênero:</label>
                         <div class="checkbox">
                           <label><input type="radio" name="SexoPet" value="Macho" checked> Macho</label>
                           <label><input type="radio" name="SexoPet" value="Fêmea"> Fêmea</label>
                         </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="form-group">
                       <label>Idade:</label>
                       <select name="IdadePet" class="form-control">
                         <option value="Antes dos 11 meses">Antes dos 11 meses</option>
                         <option value="Entre 1 e 8 anos">Entre 1 e 8 anos</option>
                       </select>
                     </div>
                    </div>
                 </div>
             </div>
       </td>
     </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <button type="button" class="adicionarCampo btn btn-primary" title="Adicionar item"><i class="fa fa-plus-square" aria-hidden="true"></i> Adicionar mais Pet</button>
        <button type="button" class="removerCampo btn btn-danger" title="Remover linha"><i class="fa fa-minus-square" aria-hidden="true"></i> Remover</button>
      </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

**JQUERY**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function () {
    function removeCampo() {
    $(".removerCampo").unbind("click");
    $(".removerCampo").bind("click", function () {
       if($("tr.linhas").length > 1){
          $(this).parent().parent().remove();
       }
    });
  }

  $(".adicionarCampo").click(function () {
    novoCampo = $("tr.linhas:first").clone();
    novoCampo.find('input[type="text"]').val("");
    novoCampo.find('select').val("");
    novoCampo.insertAfter("tr.linhas:last");
    removeCampo();
  });
});
</script>
```

O que acho estranho, é quando coloco a linha abaixo dentro de um **TD** como uma outra coluna onde está o panel, funciona:

```
<button type="button" class="removerCampo btn btn-danger" title="Remover linha"><i class="fa fa-minus-square" aria-hidden="true"></i> Remover</button>
```

Como posso resolver isso?

Comment: Fox coloca o CSS? também para eu montar o fiddle? bem melhor mano. Valeu

Comment: Olá Leonardo. Na verdade estou usando o Bootstrap. Não tenho um CSS específico para ele. São só esses códigos que compõe a dúvida mesmo.

Comment: De boa, foi mais uma mania minha de deixar o fiddle bonitinho kkk, resolvi o problema só estou explicando o porque estava se comportando daquele jeito 1min.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você estava usando `$(this).parent().parent().remove();` ou seja, de baixo para cima os elementos eram: `button` > `td` > `tr` você estava removendo o `tr` que compõe os dois botões e não o `tr` que compõe os campos do formulário.

A solução foi: `$("tr.linhas:last").remove();` do mesmo jeito que você usou `novoCampo.insertAfter("tr.linhas:last");` eu utilizei para remover o ultimo elemento adicionado.

**OBS:** acredito que o que você está fazendo na lógica de remover o PET, fere os conceitos de UX, porque digamos que você tenha colocado 300 PETS, e resolve remover o segundo dessa lista, você terá que remover 298 para chegar no segundo. Tenta adicionar botões independentes. ;)

```js
$("#remove").click(function() {
  if ($("tr.linhas").length > 1) {
    $("tr.linhas:last").remove();
  };
});


$(".adicionarCampo").click(function() {
  novoCampo = $("tr.linhas:first").clone();
  novoCampo.find('input[type="text"]').val("");
  novoCampo.find('select').val("");
  novoCampo.insertAfter("tr.linhas:last");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border="0" style="width: 100%">
  <tr class='linhas'>
    <td>
      <div class="panel panel-primary">
        <div class="panel-heading">
          <i class="fa fa-paw fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i> DADOS DO PET
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">
          <div class="table-responsive">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label>Espécie:</label>
              <select name="Especie" class="form-control">
                            <option value="Canino">Canino</option>
                            <option value="Felino">Felino</option>
                          </select>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label>Nome do Pet:</label>
              <input type="text" name="NomePet" class="form-control" required="required">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label>Aniversário do Pet:</label>
              <input type="date" name="AniversarioPet" class="form-control" data-inputmask="'alias': '99/99/9999'" required="required">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label>Gênero:</label>
              <div class="checkbox">
                <label><input type="radio" name="SexoPet" value="Macho" checked> Macho</label>
                <label><input type="radio" name="SexoPet" value="Fêmea"> Fêmea</label>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label>Idade:</label>
              <select name="IdadePet" class="form-control">
                         <option value="Antes dos 11 meses">Antes dos 11 meses</option>
                         <option value="Entre 1 e 8 anos">Entre 1 e 8 anos</option>
                       </select>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <button type="button" class="adicionarCampo btn btn-primary" title="Adicionar item"><i class="fa fa-plus-square" aria-hidden="true"></i> Adicionar mais Pet</button>
      <button type="button" id="remove" class="removerCampo btn btn-danger" title="Remover linha"><i class="fa fa-minus-square" aria-hidden="true"></i> Remover</button>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Perfeito Leonardo. Funcionou! Na verdade irei limitar apenas 10 Pets. Muito obrigado pela ajuda.

Comment: You're welcome !

Answer (score 0):

A lógica de formatação não está legal, utilize `<table>` apenas para dados tabulares, mas se ainda sim quiser usar `<table>`, deixe os botões de adicionar e remover fora da tabela.

Exemplo simples usando jQuery:

```js
$(function(){ 
  var pets = $('.pets');
  var maximo_de_pets = 10;
  $('.add').click(function(){
    if (pets.find('tr').length < maximo_de_pets){
      var novo_pet = pets.find('tr').first().clone();
      novo_pet.find('input[type="text"]').val("");
      novo_pet.find('select').val("");
      pets.append(novo_pet);
    }
    else{
     alert('maximo ' + maximo_de_pets + ' pets')
    }
  });
  $('.conteudo').on('click', '.remover', function(){
    if(pets.find('tr').length > 1){
      if ($(this).hasClass('ultimo')){
        pets.find('tr').last().remove();
      }
      else{
        $(this).closest('tr').remove();
      }
    }
    else{
      alert('minimo 1 pet');
    }
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='conteudo'>
<table class="pets">
<tr><td>blabla <button class='remover'>remover</button></td></tr>
</table>
<div class="botoes">
  <button class="add">Adicionar</button>
  <button class="remover ultimo">Remover ultimo</button>
</div>
</div>
```